# running a green screen video in another video

Tags: html, video, canvas

I would like to ask why can't I run two different source of video which is .ogg and .mp4 files in this canvas. I am trying to override this green screen video to another video that had it's background colour hidden.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      function load() {
        var get1 = document.getElementById("c1");
        var set1 = get1.getContext("2d");

        var get2 = document.getElementById("c2");
        var set2 = get2.getContext("2d");

        var video1 = document.getElementById("video1");
        var video2 = document.getElementById("video2");

        video1.addEventListener('play', function(){runVideo();});
        video2.addEventListener('play', function(){runVideo2();});

        var runVideo1 = function() {
          if(video1.paused || video1.ended) {
            return;
          }

          var frameconversion = function() {
            if(window.requestAnimationFrame) {
              requestAnimationFrame(runVideo1);
            } else {
              setTimeout(runVideo,0);
            }
          };
        };

        var runVideo2 = function() {
          if(video2.paused || video2.ended) {
            return;
          }

          var frameconversion2 = function() {
            if(window.requestAnimationFrame) {
              requestAnimationFrame(runVideo2);
            } else {
              setTimeout(runVideo2,0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()" style="background:grey">
    <video id = "video1" controls="true">
      <source src = "video.ogg" />
    </video>
    <video id = "video2" controls="true">
      <source src = "Helicopter Bell Fly By with Sound on green screen - free green screen 6.mp4" />
    </video>
    <canvas id = "c1" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id = "c2" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your functions do nothing except calling each other ?

Comment: This link may also be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas although it does not answer the question directly.

Answer (score 3):

[This article on Metia](http://www.metia.com/london/mark-mower/2012/12/building-an-html5-green-screen-%28chroma-key%29-dynamic-video-player/) shows a working HTML5 example of green-screen (chroma key) video in a canvas. As you can see, it allows you two change the background to a selection of static images **and video** sources.